# How do I create a Vec from a range and shuffle it?

Tags: iterator, immutability, rust, mutability

I have the following code:

```
extern crate rand;

use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};

fn main() {
    let mut vec: Vec<u32> = (0..10).collect();
    let mut slice: &[u32] = vec.as_mut_slice();

    thread_rng().shuffle(slice);
}
```

and get the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:9:26
  |
9 |     thread_rng().shuffle(slice);
  |                          ^^^^^ types differ in mutability
  |
  = note: expected type `&mut [_]`
             found type `&[u32]`
```

I think I understand that the content of vectors and slices is immutable and that causes the error here, but I'm unsure.

The signature of `as_mut_slice` is `pub fn as_mut_slice<'a>(&'a mut self) -> &'a mut [T]`, so the slice should be mutable, but it somehow isn't.

I know that there must be an easy fix, but I tried my best and couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

### Rand v0.6.0

The `Rng::shuffle` method is now deprecated; `rand::seq::SliceRandom` trait should be used. It provides the `shuffle()` method on all slices, which accepts an `Rng` instance:

```
// Rust edition 2018 no longer needs extern crate

use rand::thread_rng;
use rand::seq::SliceRandom;

fn main() {
    let mut vec: Vec<u32> = (0..10).collect();
    vec.shuffle(&mut thread_rng());
    println!("{:?}", vec);
}
```

See it [on Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=061c00d71c5b97db2a6e5d39d5e7ce37).

### Original answer

You're very close. This should work:

```
extern crate rand;

use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};

fn main() {
    let mut vec: Vec<u32> = (0..10).collect();
    let slice: &mut [u32] = &mut vec;

    thread_rng().shuffle(slice);
}
```

`&mut [T]` is implicitly coercible to `&[T]`, and you annotated the `slice` variable with `&[u32]`, so the slice became immutable: `&mut [u32]` was coerced to `&[u32]`. `mut` on the variable is not relevant here because slices are just borrows into data owned by someone else, so they do not have inherited mutability - their mutability is encoded in their types.

In fact, you don't need an annotation on `slice` at all. This works as well:

```
extern crate rand;

use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};

fn main() {
    let mut vec: Vec<u32> = (0..10).collect();
    let slice = vec.as_mut_slice();

    thread_rng().shuffle(slice);
}
```

You don't even need the intermediate variable:

```
extern crate rand;

use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};

fn main() {
    let mut vec: Vec<u32> = (0..10).collect();
    thread_rng().shuffle(&mut vec);
}
```

You should read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/index.html) as it explains the concepts of ownership and borrowing and how they interact with mutability.

---

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Unfortunately, I pasted your code into the Rust Playground (https://play.rust-lang.org/) and discovered that `thread_rng().shuffle` is now deprecated.  Do you know how we're supposed to shuffle a vector now?  (I think we're supposed to use a trait, but I'm not experienced enough in Rust to know how to do that yet.)

Comment: With rand, version 0.7.0 the `Rng::shuffle` method was removed. You are now required to use the `SliceRandom::shuffle` method.

Answer (score 20):

You can use [`shuffle`](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/seq/trait.SliceRandom.html#tymethod.shuffle) like this:

```
extern crate rand;

use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let mut vec: Vec<usize> = (0..10).collect();
    println!("{:?}", vec);
    rand::thread_rng().shuffle(&mut vec);
    println!("{:?}", vec);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Unfortunately, I pasted your code into the Rust Playground (https://play.rust-lang.org/) and discovered that `thread_rng().shuffle` is now deprecated.  Do you know how we're supposed to shuffle a vector now?  (I think we're supposed to use a trait, but I'm not experienced enough in Rust to know how to do that yet.)

Comment: @J-L, I see. Thanks. I tried to do it the other way: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=74022e6f3a22741b98782ade77531691, but I am getting different warnings, not sure if this is a better solution.

Comment: These two compiler warnings don't seem to make sense.
- One is telling "unused variable: `rng`" which is clearly wrong, you are using rng in the call to the shuffle method.
- The other is saying that the rng "variable does not need to be mutable "which is also wrong because we need a mutable reference of rng in the call to shuffle on the vec.