# How to shuffle an array deterministically with a seed?

Tags: random, rust, shuffle, random-seed

I'm finding it difficult to shuffle an array deterministically, *i.e.* with a random seed in Rust. What I'm trying to achieve (in pseudo code):

```
let v = vec![0, 1, 2, 3];
pseudo_shuffle(v, randomSeed1) // always produces e.g. [3,1,2,0]
pseudo_shuffle(v, randomSeed2) // always produces e.g. [0,2,3,1]
```

[In another Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26035435/4070218) I learnt how to use [`rand::Rng::shuffle()`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.4.2/rand/trait.Rng.html#method.shuffle) to shuffle a vector non-deterministically, but it doesn't seem to provide an API for applying a random seed to the generation function, and I'm having a difficult time coming up with a solution myself that doesn't employ some ridiculous `n!` complexity algorithm.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a random number generator that implements the trait [`SeedableRng`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.6.5/rand/trait.SeedableRng.html) and call [`from_seed`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.6.5/rand/trait.SeedableRng.html#tymethod.from_seed) with the desired seed.

Example:

```
use rand::{seq::SliceRandom, SeedableRng}; // 0.6.5
use rand_chacha::ChaChaRng; // 0.1.1

fn main() {
    let seed = [0; 32];
    let mut rng = ChaChaRng::from_seed(seed);

    let mut v1 = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    v1.shuffle(&mut rng);
    assert_eq!(v1, [3, 5, 2, 4, 1]);
}
```

Clone the RNG before using it or create a new one from scratch with the same seed to reset back to the original state.

You may also be interested in [`ReseedingRng`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.6.5/rand/rngs/adapter/struct.ReseedingRng.html) as well.

Comment: Completely missed that trait, I'm a donut. Thanks so much!