# Is there a way to shuffle a slice of tuples without implementing the RandCore trait for it?

Tags: rust

Suppose I had the following variable:

```
let mut n: &[((usize, usize), (usize, usize))];
```

I'd like to shuffle some data in this variable. I tried:

```
rng.shuffle(&mut n); // rng is of type rand::Rng
```

which of course leads to a compiler error complaining that the trait `RandCore` isn't implemented for that type. I don't really mind implementing it, but I'd hate to have to define a trait implementation for every variation of that type (e.g. `(usize, isize)`, `((usize, isize), (usize, isize), (isize, usize))`, etc) that I have in my code.

Is there another way of "automatically" defining this trait (like using macros of some sort)?

Comment: In addition to the ordering problem pointed out in the answer, perhaps you need to explicitly `use rand::seq::SliceRandom` to get the `RandCore` trait implemented for slices.

Comment: See the answers here for how to properly shuffle a slice: [How do I create a Vec from a range and shuffle it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033976/how-do-i-create-a-vec-from-a-range-and-shuffle-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the arguments the wrong way round. It should be `n.shuffle(&mut rng)`. `RandCore` is the trait for an rng, not a value to be shuffled. You should then find `SliceRandom` is implemented for all slices if you use it.

Comment: Wow! Indeed works like magic. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1c83c8fa203105272e55917eaad03d9e)

Comment: Whoops. Looks like I looked at some outdated documentation :(